# Best way: to implement an interrupt/cancel feature for all your threaded workers

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading

So my question is how to implement cancel/interrupt feature into all (I mean ALL) thread workers in your application in best and most elegant way?

It's not important if it's an HttpWebRequest, IO operation or calculation. User should have an possibility to cancel every action/thread at any moment.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use .NET 4.0 `Task`s with `CancellationToken`s - they are the new universal cancellation system.

Comment: I agree with Stephen's answer as far as the method of notification.  As for how to actually handle the cancellation, that would need to be determined separately for each asynchronous task, as different processes will have different points at which they can be safely canceled, may require rollback if changes are not complete, etc.  Not all preexisting asynchronous calls even support cancellation.

Comment: Good point, Dan. Most asynchronous calls do support different types of cancellation, but some do not. Worst-case scenario is to have notification "orphan" the operation if it can't be cancelled, so it will eventually complete in the background, discarding the results.

Answer (score 5):

> User should have an possibility to
>   cancel every action/thread at any
>   moment.

Threading is a practice, not a design... and believe me it has been tried as a design, but it failed miserably. The basic problem with simply canceling **any action** at **any moment** is that in a multithreaded environment it's just **evil**! Imagine that you have a section of code guarded by a lock and you have two threads running in parallel:

1. Thread 1 acquires the lock.
2. Thread 2 waits until the lock is released so it can acquire it.
3. Thread 1 is canceled while it's holding the lock and it doesn't release the lock.
4. **DEADLOCK**: Thread 2 is waiting for the lock which will **never** be released.

This is the simplest example and technically we can take care of this situation in the design, i.e. automatically release any locks that the thread has acquired, but instead of locks think of object states, resource utilization, client dependencies, etc. If your thread is modifying a big object and it's canceled in the middle of the modification, then the state of the object may be inconsistent, the resource which you're utilizing might get hung up, the client depending on that thread might crash... there is a slew of things which can happen and there is simply no way to design for them. In this case you make it a **practice** to manage the threads: **you** ensure a safe cancellation of your threads.

Others have already mentioned various methods for starting threads that can be canceled, but I just wanted to touch on the principles. Even in the cases where there is a way to cancel your threads, you **still** have to keep in mind that you're responsible for determining the *safest* way to cancel your thread.

> It's not important if it's an HttpWebRequest, IO operation or calculation.

I hope now you understand why it's **the MOST important** thing! Unless you specifically know what your thread is doing, then there is no safe way to automatically cancel it.

P.S.
One thing to remember is that if you don't want hanging threads then for each one of them you can set the `Thread.IsBackground` flag to `true` and they will automatically be closed when your application exits.

Answer (score 0):

Your worker threads need a way to check with your main thread to see if they should keep going. One way is to share a `static volatile bool` that's set by your UI and periodically checked by the worker threads.

My preference is to create your own threads that run instances of a worker class that periodically invoke a callback method provided by your main thread. This callback returns a value that tells the worker to continue, pause, or stop.

Avoid the temptation to use Thread.Abort() to kill worker threads: [Manipulating a thread from a different thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/771134/manipulating-a-thread-from-a-different-thread).